# Can Istio work in an environment with higher latency, drops?

Tags: networking, istio

I plan to deploy a service mesh in an environment where I have higher latencies than your usual DC. Will Istio break? Can it be adapted to such an environment?

This is a new customer environment I baselined in preparation for a service mesh deployment. I did not deploy Istio or Linkerd under such conditions before so I am wondering if anyone has done it or know any knobs to make the mesh deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Istio has a [feature](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#HTTPRetry) to retry HTTP request to back-end service if it fails.

Istio and Kubernetes configurations are declarative, therefore if some packets drop they will be resend due to TCP protocol capabilities and application fail-proof design. But high latency and drops may significantly impact the cluster performance and time required for applying changes.

Comment: Thanks VAS. I dug a bit more into this and found a few useful points. On one hand you can manage request -timeouts (https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-timeouts/) even though the defaults are way about what I expect would define this environment. On the other hand, there was a request for enabling the ability to manage the mesh TCP timeouts to upstream clusters (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/9378).